# Rename Tag for Cortana

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

After reading this [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87437/how-to-rename-a-tag), Id like to make the following rename request to a moderator.

[cortana-analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cortana-analytics) -> [cortana-intelligence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cortana-intelligence)

I created the Cortana Analytics tag, and my team at Microsoft uses this tag as a way to engage with our community. But the suite has been recently rebranded to Cortana Intelligence. See [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/solutions/cortana-intelligence/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[cortana-analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cortana-analytics) has been syn'd and renamed to [cortana-intelligence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cortana-intelligence)